# How can i auto update my database in django rest?

Tags: python, django

I have to make a order status, where there are 3 columns: orderId, item_name, status. An order can have multiple items, and every item can have diferemt status. So what i have to do is an endpoint that return the status of the order. Example: if the order 1, has 3 items, and 2 of the items have the status: "Shipped" and the other is "Pending", the expected result of that order status is "Pending", because not all the item have been shipped.

models.py

```
 from django.db import models
import requests


class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    choice = (('SHIPPED', 'SHIPPED'), ('PENDING', 'PENDING'), ('CANCELLED', 'CANCELLED'))
    OrderNumber = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=choice)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.OrderNumber


class OrderItems(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    choice = (('SHIPPED', 'SHIPPED'), ('PENDING', 'PENDING'), ('CANCELLED', 'CANCELLED'))
    itemName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    OrderNumber = models.ForeignKey(OrderStatus, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=choice)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status
```

Views.py

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from OrderStatus.api.serializers import OrderRegisterSerializer, NumberOrderSerializer
from OrderStatus.models import OrderItems, OrderStatus


class OrderApiViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = OrderRegisterSerializer
    queryset = OrderItems.objects.all()



class OrderNumberApiviewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = NumberOrderSerializer
    queryset = OrderStatus.objects.all()
```

serializers.py

```
from OrderStatus.models import OrderItems, OrderStatus
from rest_framework import serializers


class OrderRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #items = serializers.RelatedField(many=True, queryset = OrderItems.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItems
        fields = ['itemName', 'OrderNumber', 'status']
        order_by = 'OrderNumber'


class NumberOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #test = serializers.CharField(source='OrderItems.status', read_only=True)
    #data= OrderItems.objects.filter(OrderNumber__contains= = '1')
    class Meta:
        model = OrderStatus
        fields = ['OrderNumber', 'status', 'OrderItems']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert status field to a property something like this:

```
class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    choice = (('SHIPPED', 'SHIPPED'), ('PENDING', 'PENDING'), ('CANCELLED', 'CANCELLED'))
    OrderNumber = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.OrderNumber
    @property
    def status(self)->str:
        # do your logic to get the correct status here
        return "SHIPPED"
```

then in the serializer add:

```
status = serializers.CharField(required=False, read_only=True)
```

Comment: obv you can access your items by order.items.all(). You may want to prefetch_related for optimization, but later...